# PHP Restricting Access to web pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, restriction

I have several folders within my web server.
Each folder contains php / html files. In total there is around 40 files.

Using php I can determine the identity of the user who is currently logged in.

Is it possible to allow users to only access specific pages, based on who they are logged in as ?

I was wondering if `.htaccess` would allow this ? Or if there is a better way ?

I don't really want to start having to create a user / password authentication script.

Thanks

Comment: You will probably want to use sessions for this.

Comment: what types of files are in your directory?

Comment: Without some sort of authentication you'r not going to be able to do this. How are you identifying the user now?

Comment: how do users log in? are their credentials saved in a session? how many users does your system have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sessions, you can create user levels and restrict access to various areas by assigning user levels to `SESSION` variables. Presumably, since, quote `Using php I can determine the identity of the user who is currently logged in.`, you have the ability to set up session variables. I believe this is known as role based access control - In it's very simplest form

```
if ($_SESSION['user_level'] == "Administrator") {
# do something
}
```

[This article may help further](http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/)

Comment: Thanks this has helped. As the users have to login initially to access the main site, I can use roles to allow or deny access to other areas.

Comment: Glad it was of some use :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will redirect all users trying to view a PHP page to `index.php?p=someurl.php`

Then in your index.php you can determine if the user has permission to view to file and if they do serve it, if not deny it.

```
if ( authorized() ) {
  // show file
} else {
  die("Not Authorized to Access this File.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access *SESSION*s from **.htaccess** rules, but you can try a workaround if you're not willing to code.

Inside your authorizing code section, in the last lines after creating session, add a `touch()` to create a file name of current user session id:

```
touch("./folder/logged/PHPSESSID_".session_id());
```

Then within your **.htaccess** file try to validate if current PHPSESSID related file is created before:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} PHPSESSID=(\w+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/logged/PHPSESSID_%1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1
RewriteRule .* /users/login [L]
```

---

** Also note that you should create a simple script to check if created files are valid anymore, if not then remove them.*

** It's just an idea!*